# XPath селектор элементов с тем же значением атрибута

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

Пусть есть элементы XML:

```
<DOCUMENT SIZE="10x15" TYPE="ФОТОБУМАГА СТАНДАРТ" COUNT="2" PRICE="10" PRICE2="9" PRICE3="7">
<DOCUMENT SIZE="15x21" TYPE="ФОТОБУМАГА СТАНДАРТ" COUNT="3" PRICE="30" PRICE2="25" PRICE3="20" >
<DOCUMENT SIZE="10x15" TYPE="ФОТОБУМАГА СТАНДАРТ" COUNT="4" PRICE="10" PRICE2="9" PRICE3="7">
```

Они имеют разные значения атрибута `SIZE`.

Нужно в шаблоне для каждого элемента `<document>` подсчитать общее количество таких же по размеру и типу элементов:

Вот код шаблона, но процессор, почему-то, выбирает все элементы вместо нужных:

```
    <xsl:template match="DOCUMENT" mode="sum">
       <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
       <xsl:variable name="curid" select="@ID"/>
       <!-- Тип текущего элемента -->
       <xsl:variable name="type" select="/PAGE/CONTENT/BASKET/UPLOADIMG/DOCUMENT[@ID=$curid]/@TYPE"/>
       <!-- Размер текущего элемента -->
       <xsl:variable name="size" select="/PAGE/CONTENT/BASKET/UPLOADIMG/DOCUMENT[@ID=$curid]/@SIZE"/>
       <!-- Подсчет кол-ва однотипных элементов для текущего элемента -->
       <xsl:variable name="count" select="sum(/PAGE/CONTENT/BASKET/UPLOADIMG/DOCUMENT[@SIZE=$size and @TYPE=$type]/@COUNT)"/>
       <xsl:variable name="price">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$count &lt; 100"><xsl:value-of select="/PAGE/CONTENT/BASKET/UPLOADIMG/DOCUMENT[@ID=$curid]/@PRICE"/></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$count &lt; 201"><xsl:value-of select="/PAGE/CONTENT/BASKET/UPLOADIMG/DOCUMENT[@ID=$curid]/@PRICE2"/></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$count &gt; 200"><xsl:value-of select="/PAGE/CONTENT/BASKET/UPLOADIMG/DOCUMENT[@ID=$curid]/@PRICE3"/></xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:variable>
       <!--
       count-<xsl:value-of select="$count"/><br />
       price-<xsl:value-of select="$price"/><br />
       -->
       <xsl:variable name="curSum" select="$sum + $price*@COUNT"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::DOCUMENT[1]" mode="sum">
          <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$curSum"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
       <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::DOCUMENT[1])">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$curSum&gt;0"><xsl:value-of select="$curSum"/></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Какой у вас процессор XSLT и его соответствие стандартам XSLT: 1.0, 2.0 или 3.0.?

Answer (score 0):

Все работает, просто я не совсем внимательно посмотрел шаблон. В файле шаблона 4 таких похожих друг на друга участка. По два на корзину и письмо электронной почты, и в каждой из этих двух сущностей отдельный подсчет для товара и итоговый расчет.
Селектор верный.